# How to store array in database in multiple columns and every n-th array element start storing from first column (Java and OracleXE213)

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am working on one interesting project. I have text file (it is lot longer by rows, and lines are approximately 800 chars-the actual size does not matter because it can change) that looks like this:

MyNameoooDDMMGGGMyAdressoooMYDogNameooo000088800000888777
YourNameoDDMMGGGYourAdressoYourDogNameo000088800000888666
MyNameoooDDMMGGGMyAdressoooMYDogNameooo0000888000008887777

And so on...

I have managed to read file, split lines and store it in to List.
Console output of the List (`copy()`) looks like this:

- MyName000
- DDMMGGG
- MyAdress000
- MYDogName000
- 0000888
- 00000888
- 777
- YourName*
- DDMMGGG
- YourAdress0
- YourDogName0
- 0000888
- 00000888
- 666
- MyName000
- DDMMGGG
- MyAdress000
- MYDogName000
- 0000888
- 00000888
- 777

and so on..

Now the fun part is to store that data in to database. Starting from **MyName000** to **column1** and to last peace of data of first line **777** to last **column7** and from second line**YourName0** to first **column1**....last piece of data in second line **666** to last **column7**.
Note: For now I have 60 columns in database and text file have around 200 000 lines. It is big.

Code for database entry:

```
try {

            PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement(prep);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < copy.size()-1; i++) {
                
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfColumns.length - 1; j++) {
                    
                    statement.setString(j + 1, copy.get(j));

                    //statement.addBatch();
                     statement.execute();
                    
                }
                //statement.executeBatch();
                 statement.executeUpdate();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

'''
I have tried lot's of things, and I don't know is this right way to do this task from the start.
I got error:

java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2033)
at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3751)
at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4136)
at com.oracle.database.jdbc/oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1014)
at Demo.main(Demo.java:69)

`statement.execute();` is at line 69

prepstatment:

```
String prep= "insert into AAA"
                + "(column1, column2, column3, colum4, column5, column6,"
                + " column7)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

listo of columns:

```
String listOfColumns[] = { "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4",
                "column5", "column6", "column7" };
```

With iterator it is same thing:

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```java
for (int j = 0; j < listOfColumns.length - 1; j++) {
```

It will loop from `0` to `5` (since `5` is less than `(7 - 1)`) but you want it to reach `6`.

Change it to:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < listOfColumns.length; j++) {
    statement.setString(j + 1, copy.get(j));
```

Comment: Same Exception >> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2.